# Is there any configurations needed to my route 53 service when adding an SSL to my cloud front distribution?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have built a git backed static site that lives in an S3 bucket and is updated with a Code Pipeline. The site is fully hosted on AWS. The Route 53 name servers point to the S3 bucket but I have recently created a Cloudfront distribution that points to the S3 bucket so I am able to have a SSL certificate. The problem is I believe when you go to the sites url it still points to the S3 bucket and not the Cloudfront distribution. Could this be due to a Route 53 config issue?

The SSL certificated is ACM are active and hosted in (US East)N. Virgina and have been added to the custom SSL certificate in the Cloudfront distribution.

the Cloudfront distribution origin is the S3 bucket with it being "domainname.s3.amazonaws.com" (there are two distributions one for domainname.com and www.domainname.com pointing to each bucket respectivley.

I know a common fix for this is to wait for cloudfront to find the bucket and so I have waited 24 hours before asking the question.

If there is any more information I need to provide please let me know I have tried to proved as much as possible but there is something I am probably overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have to update your Route53 configuration.

[As the docs say:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)

> If you want to use your own domain name, use Amazon Route 53 to create
>   an alias record that points to your CloudFront distribution. An alias
>   record is a Route 53 extension to DNS. It's similar to a CNAME record,
>   but you can create an alias record both for the root domain, such as
>   example.com, and for subdomains, such as www.example.com. (You can
>   create CNAME records only for subdomains.) When Route 53 receives a
>   DNS query that matches the name and type of an alias record, Route 53
>   responds with the domain name that is associated with your
>   distribution.

You can also check your domain whit a `nslookup` or `dig` and see what does the domain resolve, that way you can ensure if it is pointing to your CloudFront distribution

```
nslookup yourdomain.com
```

The result of the dig / nslookup should show you something like:

`<hash>.cloudfront.net.` and that resolving to multiple IP addresses

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to add that I added the CNAME record too. The ACM has a button that does it if you host with Route 53. I will try the nslookup

Comment: With using nslookup a few times I can see that the address is not static so it must not be pointing to the cloudfront dist?

Comment: Correct, you should see something like 'asdasdasdasda.cloudfront.net.' and that resolving to multiple IP's

Comment: And so I need to configure route 53 to point exclusively to the cloudfront ?

Comment: Yes, you want your Route53 to point to your CDN distribution, but remember that every time you update the website content in the S3 bucket you need to invalidate the cache of the distribution so you can see your changes. More details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html